# hide or remove black bars on html5 video tag

Tags: android, html5-video

We developed a mobile web Application where videos using HTML5 video tag are streamed.
On tablet nexus 10 android version 4.3 when the user play the video black bars appear on top and bottom.
is it possible to hide or remove these black bars?

This is the code:

```
<div class="term-video bottom" style="width: 800px; height:600px">
    <video style="width: 800px; height: 600px" poster="resourcePath" preload="auto" loop="loop" webkit-playsinline>
        <source src="videoPath" />
    </video>
</div>
```

on Android phone works fine.